# Printing star greater symbol in Java

Tags: java, ascii-art

I need to print this in Java, but I feel that my code is too big:

> ```
> *
> **
> ***
> ****
> ***
> **
> *
> ```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int i=0; i<=3; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<=i; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    for(int j=1; j<=3; j++) {
        for(int i=3; i>=j; i--) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is a lovely way to do it using only one nested for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (int numStars = 0; numStars < 4 - Math.abs(3 - i); numStars++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This uses the Math.abs function to perform the calculation of how many stars to print.

If we take a look at a plot of the classic [Math.abs](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=abs%28x%29&t=mfftb01) we can see that it looks useful. We need to flip it upside-down though, this is done by taking `4 - abs(x)` which would [look like this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4+-+abs%28x%29). Finally, we need to switch it to the right a bit, so we modify the input to the function call and end up with this: [4 - abs(3 - x)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4+-+abs%283+-+x%29)

Images courtesy of [wolframalpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com)

#### 4-abs(x)

[image]

#### 4-abs(3 - x)

[image]

Finally, here is a very flexible solution, which also works with even numbers:

```
int rows = 20;
double maximumValue = Math.ceil(rows / 2.0);
double shifted = maximumValue - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    int count = (int) (maximumValue - Math.abs(shifted - i));
    if (i >= rows / 2 && rows % 2 == 0) // slight fix for even number of rows
        count++;
    
    for (int numStars = 0; numStars < count; numStars++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This will output:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I am disappointed that @user3272408 was apparently only interested in the code.

Comment: +5 for charts and graphs! Letterman would be proud.

Answer (score 16):

You've hard-coded `3` in three places.  Yet, the output contains a row with four stars.  That's **underhanded programming**.  The culprit is this line:

```
for(int j=0; j<=i; j++)
```

Idiomatic Java would be either

```
for (int j = 0; j < somelimit; j++)
```

or

```
for (int j = 1; j <= somelimit; j++)
```

I also find the way that you interchanged `i` and `j` between the first and second halves of the program disconcerting.

---

Surely you should define a **function that accepts a parameter**.  What varies?  The fill character?  The size?  Otherwise, the simplest solution would be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("*\n**\n***\n****\n***\n**\n*");
}
```

---

I am in favour of keeping two for-loops, one increasing and one decreasing.  Combining those into one loop would likely make it difficult to **see the intent at a glance**.  As for how you generate each line of *n* stars, though, it's not particularly interesting how you accomplish it.  I've chosen a one-line hack for the solution below, but you may wish to pick a more traditional approach.

```
private static String repeat(String s, int n) {
    // A bit of a hack, and not very efficient.  Feel free to reimplement.
    return String.format("%" + n + "s", "").replaceAll(" ", s);
}

public static void printArrow(String fill, int width, PrintStream out) {
    for (int i = 1; i < width; i++) {
        out.println(repeat(fill, i));
    }
    for (int i = width; i >= 1; i--) {
        out.println(repeat(fill, i));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printArrow("*", 4, System.out);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a loop for this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ln = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        System.out.println("*" + ln
                        +  "**" + ln
                        +  "***" + ln
                        +  "****" + ln
                        +  "***" + ln
                        +  "**" + ln
                        +  "*");
}
```

Comment: That is overkill: `System.out.println("*\n**\n***\n****\n***\n**\n*");` Seriously, what were you thinking?   ;-)  !

Comment: @rolfl: But it looks like the output itself! ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Using multiple `print("*")` calls for each star is very inefficient. Print is a slow command, and it also makes what is a relatively simple process (printing a line of stars) become a more complicated loop.

A more efficient way to output the triangle would be to use one `println` per line. An even better way would be for one println for the whole puzzle, but that has a potential issue of the `n` value is large.

A real trick here would be to build up one String value for the longest line, and then just print substrings for the shorter ones.

Note, using `Math.abs(...)` is a clever way to manipulate the substring, but combining it with a loop from `negative width` to `positive width` makes it even easier to understand.

Additionally, putting the code in to its own method, instead of the main method, makes the code more reusable.

```
public static final void triangle(int width) {
    String longest = buildLine(width, '*');

    for (int i = -width + 1; i < width; i++) {
        System.out.println(longest.substring(Math.abs(i)));
    }
}

private static String buildLine(int width, char c) {
    char[] chars = new char[width];
    Arrays.fill(chars, c);
    return new String(chars);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    triangle(5);
}
```