# Triangled printing

Tags: python, formatting

This code prints numbers in a triangled way, such as:

```
1
12
123
12
1
```

This is the code:

```
def triangled(num):
    num = str(num)
    pieces = [num[:i] for i in range(len(num))]
    return pieces + [num] + pieces[::-1]

def triangled_print(num):
    for i in triangled(num):
        print(i)

triangled_print(123456789)
```

Comment: You might also be interested in this one: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/40880/31562

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code looks fine.

I have a few suggestions, but these are nitpicks rather than major problems:

- Give your functions better names. I'd suggest `triangle_lines` and `triangle_print`, because `triangled` is just a bit ambiguous. Along the same lines, consider adding docstrings so that the user can more easily find out how your code works.
- In the final line of `triangled`, I'd write it slightly differently:

  ```
  return pieces + [num] + list(reversed(pieces))
  ```

  There's nothing wrong with taking a reverse slice, but I think this makes it slightly clearer what's going on.
- If you used this code on a really long number, you might start to have memory problems with the list returned from `triangled(<bignum>)`. You could rewrite it to be a generator, but it's not essential if you're only going to be using this for small numbers.
- Your triangle has a blank line at the top or bottom. That might be okay; if not, tweak the range to start at 1 instead of (implicit) 0:

  ```
  pieces = [num[:i] for i in range(1, len(num))]
  ```