# Printing an arrow of asterisks in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ascii-art

This code will print an arrow of asterisks, like:

```
*
**
***
****
***
**
*
```

---

```
raisingAsterisks, decreasingAsterisks, arrow :: Int -> [String]
raisingAsterisks n = take n $ iterate ('*' :) "*"
decreasingAsterisks = reverse . raisingAsterisks
arrow n = raisingAsterisks n ++ (tail (decreasingAsterisks n))

main :: IO()
main = mapM_ putStrLn $ arrow 4
```

Comment: Related: A [Java version](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/40880/31562) of the same thing. Maybe some inspiration? (I don't speak Haskell much)

Comment: @SimonForsberg yes, I just write a program in Haskell to get the same output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you're actually generating the list of Strings seems fine, but the formatting, at least in my opinion, can be improved: since raisingAsterisks and decreasingAsterisks are both relatively small "helper" functions for arrow, I would suggest putting them inside a where clause to make things a little easier to read.

```
arrow :: Int -> [String]
arrow n = increasing ++ tail decreasing
    where increasing = take n $ iterate ('*' :) "*"
          decreasing = reverse increasing
```

In this context, the variable names could be shortened, due to the fact that it's easy to understand what's happening. Note that the `n` variable no longer needs to be passed, so `increasing` and `decreasing` actually are no longer even functions!

I hope you agree that changing your code just a little greatly improves readability.

Comment: I like this simplification. The best first posts are answers, welcome to CodeReview :D

Comment: Also, the increasing list is now generated only once. (And it will be kept complete in memory anyway because of `reverse`.)