# Creating a triangle

Tags: java, comparative-review, ascii-art

I have two implementation which I modified according to my need to create a triangle or a pyramid like this:

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
```

First way:

```
int num = 5;
for(int i=0;i<num;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<num-i;j++) {
         System.out.print(" ");
     }
    for(int k=0;k<=i;k++) {
        System.out.print((k==0)?"*":"**");
    }
    System.out.println();  
}
```

Second way:

```
int num = 5, spaces = num - 1, charData = 2 * num;
String str = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(spaces, " ")) + String.join("", Collections.nCopies(charData, "*"));
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) 
    System.out.println(str.substring(i, num + 2*i));
```

The second way seems shorter than the first one which takes fewer lines of code and fewer loops. I would like to find out which one is shorter and more efficient. Is there any other way the code can become shorter and more efficient with fewer loops?

Comment: possibly interesting for you: [Printing star greater symbol in Java](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/40880/31562)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, usually the more efficient code, the longer it is. Consider this:

```
public static String getTriangleString(int height) {
    if (height < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative height: " + height);
    }

    // Find the capacity that does not waste too much space and that can
    // accommodate the entire pyramid:
    int capacity = height * (height + 1) + height * (height - 1) / 2;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Math.max(0, capacity));

    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        for (int x = height - 2 - y; x >= 0; --x) {
            sb.append(' ');
        }

        sb.append('*');

        for (int x = 0; x != y; ++x) {
            sb.append("**");
        }

        if (y < height - 1) {
            sb.append('\n');
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

The above implementation should (?) be more efficient than both of your versions, and the reason is that the entire pyramid is printed to standard output only **once**. (Printing goes down the deeps of your OS kernel.)

Hope that

**Post scriptum**

Generally, I suggest you make clear separation between algorithms and the output routines. In this case, it means it would be better to have two routines: the first computing the triangle and returning it as a string; and another one manipulating it (such as printing to standard output).